How to programmatically select a specific schema in Snowpark within a Snowsight Python worksheet?
While writing the Snowpark code in a Snowsight Python worksheet, how can I select a specific schema? I know I can manually select it using the UI, but I want to select it programmatically.
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    df_sql = session.sql("SELECT CURRENT_ACCOUNT(), CURRENT_USER(), CURRENT_ROLE(), CURRENT_WAREHOUSE(), CURRENT_DATABASE(), CURRENT_SCHEMA()")
    
    return df_sql

I have been writing Snowpark code in a Snowsight Python worksheet. While I know that I can manually select a specific schema using the UI, I want to do this programmatically within my code. I have looked through the Snowpark documentation but couldn't find a clear example or method to set the schema programmatically. I was expecting to find a way to set the schema directly in my Snowpark code, similar to how it can be done in SQL with a USE SCHEMA statement.
============ Update-1 ============
I tested with the below code, but it's failing with the error GENERAL_INVALID_OBJECT_NAME for schema 'MY_SCHEMA', but this is a valid schema under the current active Database.
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark 
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col  
def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    session.use_schema('MY_SCHEMA')     
    df_sql = session.sql("SELECT CURRENT_ACCOUNT(), CURRENT_USER(), CURRENT_ROLE(), CURRENT_WAREHOUSE(), CURRENT_DATABASE(), CURRENT_SCHEMA()")          
    return df_sql 


How about using snowflake.snowpark.Session.use_schema ?

Thanks, I tested with the below code, but it's failing with the error GENERAL_INVALID_OBJECT_NAME for schema 'MY_SCHEMA', but this is a valid schema under the current active Database.
Code:
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    session.use_schema('MY_SCHEMA')
    df_sql = session.sql("SELECT CURRENT_ACCOUNT(), CURRENT_USER(), CURRENT_ROLE(), CURRENT_WAREHOUSE(), CURRENT_DATABASE(), CURRENT_SCHEMA()")
    
    return df_sql


Please update your question with any additional information, rather than adding it in comments, so that all information is in one place and it can be formatted so it’s readable

Thanks, Done, Kindly review now.

A couple of thoughts... 1) do you also need to set the database or fully-qualify the schema name e.g. session.use_schema('DTABASE_NAME.MY_SCHEMA') ? 2) Does the user running this script have permissions on the database and schema?

Session.use_schema should allow you to update the current schema as seen below:
>>> session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
>>> session.use_schema('FINANCE')
>>> session.sql("SELECT CURRENT_SCHEMA()")
<snowflake.snowpark.dataframe.DataFrame object at 0x00000286F5726890>
>>> session.sql("SELECT CURRENT_SCHEMA()").show()




"CURRENT_SCHEMA()"




FINANCE



Do you have special characters in the schema name?
